# How to run CKEditor package in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, ckeditor

Hi I use this package for `Laravel 5.2` but it doesn't work for me. Can someone help me ?

```
<script src="/vendor/unisharp/laravel-ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script src="/vendor/unisharp/laravel-ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js"></script>
<script> 
    $('textarea').ckeditor();
    // if class is prefered.
    // $('.textarea').ckeditor();
</script>
```

[My Console Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDxGt.jpg)

Comment: Did you try to load the jQuery before the ckeditor ? Maybe the CKEditor is depent on jQuery, so if you load the jQuery later on, the CKEditor can brake.

Comment: no not load editor in my page jquery is run
https://i.imgsafe.org/a1542c5.jpg

Comment: Did you try to load first the jquery and then the ckeditor ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my page code

```
@extends('layouts.app')
{!! Html::script('js/jquery.min.js') !!}
@section('content')
<div class="container spark-screen">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Dashboard</div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    <script src="/vendor/unisharp/laravel-ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
                    <script>
                        CKEDITOR.replace( 'article-ckeditor' );
                    </script>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 3):

please try to use jquery version 1.12.0, i had same issue but got it resolved using j v1.12.0

Comment: maybe you should try summernote text editor, you will love it

Answer (score 1):

By default you may use id of the textarea in replace function.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue but using the cdn link `<script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.7/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>` instead, solved my problem.

[check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35884400/ckeditor-doesnt-show-in-laravel-5)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes yo may need to point your source one level higher from the current directory.
You achieve this by adding `../` to your source directory. Check it below

```
<script src="../vendor/unisharp/laravel-ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script src="../vendor/unisharp/laravel-ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js"></script>
<script> 
    $('textarea').ckeditor();
    // if class is prefered.
    // $('.textarea').ckeditor();
</script>
```