# CKEditor doesn't show in laravel 5

Tags: laravel, ckeditor, laravel-5

I want to save some data from a webpage and for that i wanted to use CKEditor in my page. But after loading the page it's showing normal textarea instead of showing CKEditor . i followed the following process to use it:

1 Download the ckeditor.zip file, uncompressed it and placed it in 
        public > js  folder

2.then in my master page in HEAD tag i have used the following line to link it:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('assets/js/ckeditor/ckeditor.js') }}"></script`>
```

3 after that in my viewpage i have used :

```
<textarea class="form-control" id="article-ckeditor" name="description" rows="3"></textarea></br>

 <script>
        CKEDITOR.replace( 'article-ckeditor' );
    </script>
```

Comment: Does your js file return ok.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you try to cdn link to i have solve this problem in cdn link..

```
<textarea name="editor1"></textarea>
        <script>
            CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
        </script>
```

Comment: If anyone need the ckeditor cdn, here is the link:

<script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.7/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>

Comment: yes if any problem so i  integrate in ckeditor so i help you

Comment: Does this means that there is no need to download the zip version again? because the cdn link works but referencing locally does not work any tips?

Comment: I think this [Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y-SvIFS4J8o&index=6&list=PL55RiY5tL51r_qJPESCy5ScfwTo2klnlW) can help you to find the solution to run Editor locally.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the **defer** from marked line

[image: Just remove the defer from marked line]

Then it will be okay and it works fine

Answer (score 1):

Remove the assets and use as following

```
src="{{ URL::asset('js/ckeditor/ckeditor.js') }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you have ckeditor locally on your project

```
<script src="../vendor/unisharp/laravel-ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the solution is:

```
{{URL::asset('vendor/unisharp/laravel-ckeditor/ckeditor.js')}}
```

Return path is:

```
src="http://example.com/someapp/vendor/unisharp/laravel-ckeditor/ckeditor.js"
```